Django can`t find image
When i run my Django app with Daphne
daphne -e ssl:8000:privateKey=ssl/privkey.pem:certKey=ssl/cert.pem website.asgi:application`

I get
WARNING  Not Found: /media/images/lcg.jpg

I set all setiings by guids and documantation
settings.py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('shop.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

index.html
{% for product in column1 %}
  <div class="item">
    {% if product.img %}
      <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ product.img }}" alt="{{ product.name }}" class="product-img">
    {% endif %}

tried add {% get_media_prefix as MEDIA_URL %} but nothing changed
where product.img from DB - images\filename.png
and i have this structure

I had similar problen with static files but ChatGPT advised to use whitenoise and it solved problem
but not with img

What if you use <img src="{{ product.img.url }}" instead?

doesn`t help it

What's the value of the DEBUG setting? I have a suspicion that it is set to False...

yes it was False, and after i changed to True all work good. Can you say why it work, what do this setting

You shouldn't be depending on Django to serve your static media files in production, Django is inefficient at that and not built for that purpose. Check the linked duplicate.

Edit your asgi.py and add the following import:
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import ASGIStaticFilesHandler

then change the following line:
application = get_asgi_application()

to
application = ASGIStaticFilesHandler(get_asgi_application())

Also, always use {{ product.img.url }} instead of {{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ product.img }}.

unfortunately this doesn`t helped me with img but my style and js imported correctly now without  whitenoise.
but i get this error with img -
"GET /" 200 2824
WARNING  Not Found: /media/images/discord.png
"GET /media/images/discord.png" 404 179
WARNING  Not Found: /media/images/lcg.jpg
"GET /media/images/lcg.jpg" 404 179
"GET /static/style.css" 200 1578
"GET /static/script.js" 200 1472

Then it is probably your path('', include('shop.urls')),, which matches everything that starts with an empty string, including /media. Try temporarily changing it to path('shop/', include('shop.urls')), then visit http://localhost:8000/shop/
